# Different CSS output between less compilers

Tags: less

For a while, I used to compile my [less](http://lesscss.org/) using [Sublime](http://sublimetext.com/2)'s [less2css](https://github.com/timdouglas/sublime-less2css) plugin, but more recently I've started using [LiveReload](http://livereload.com/)* and I love it.

I noticed a difference between the CSS output depending on the compiler I used.

For the following LESS:

```
.gallery {
    margin-bottom: 1em;

    img {
        .wide-gallery& {
            width: 49%;

            &:nth-child(odd) {
                margin-right: 2%;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

LiveReload gave me the output I expected:

```
.gallery {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.wide-gallery.gallery img {
  width: 49%;
}
.wide-gallery.gallery img:nth-child(odd) {
  margin-right: 2%;
}
```

...but my less2css plugin in sublime mismatched my selectors:

```
.gallery {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.wide-gallery .gallery img {
  width: 49%;
}
.wide-gallery .gallery img :nth-child(odd) {
  margin-right: 2%;
}
```

Are the two compilers just using a different version of less? I'm not sure what's going on here.

*I'm using LiveReload v0.7.1.0 on Windows 8.

Comment: If you think my use of the ampersand combinator is confusing [this article](http://tylersticka.com/2012/03/27/happier-ie-fallbacks-with-css-less-and-conditional-comments) has more info.

Answer (score 1):

in my case, Crunch! did the job just fine
http://crunchapp.net/

Comment: LiveReload compiled my less correctly too, *and refreshes my browser* (yes I'm lazy). Could be a bug with less2css? I've tried Crunch before. 'Tis a pretty cool app, but I prefer to do all my dev'ing in one text editor (sublime is awesome).